# RedirectResponse not able to redirect in hook_entity_view drupal 8

Tags: 8, hooks

I am trying to redirect users to a page on entity view. I am using RedirectResponse in hook_entity_view. But it is not redirecting to the desired page.

This is how I implemented this.
After fetching my redirect url, I have passed it to RedirectResponse.

return new RedirectResponse($redirect_url);

Thank you

Comment: You should provide your code or some similar code sample.

Comment: First, review the change log here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537. Second, post your code. Third, ensure the code is being hit by debugging it.

Comment: Consider implementing a request event subscriber instead, you can then look for a certain route and e.g. node type and redirect there. That's the only correct way to set a redirect response, sending them yourself in arbitrary code is discouraged.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you, I got it working.
Don't need to return the object of RedirectResponse. It works like this.

$response = new RedirectResponse($redirect_url);

$response->send();

It works this way.

Answer (score 4):

After filling in the prompts with Drupal Console after executing `drupal generate:event:subscriber`, and entering `kernel.request` when prompted for the event name, it's possible to add something like the following to the callback function that handles the event:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
...
 /**
   * This method is called whenever the kernel.request event is
   * dispatched.
   *
   * @param GetResponseEvent $event
   */
  public function kernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $route_name = $request->attributes->get('_route');

    if ($route_name == 'entity.checkout.canonical') {

     // Create the destination URL, such as:
      $url = Url::fromRoute('user.register')->toString();

      // create redirect:
      $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
      $response->send();
    }
  }
```