# How to force a redirect (override the destination query string in the URL)

Tags: 8, forms, routes

I have a custom form submit callback to redirect users to a specific page:

```
function MYMODULE_authfrontpageredirect_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  $url = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid('node/16');
  $form_state->setRedirect($url->getRouteName(), $url->getRouteParameters());
}
```

This works correctly unless the url has a `destination` query string, such as
`/node/add/mynode?destination=/user`

In this case, the user will be redirected based on the query string (to `/user`) instead of my submit handler destination (`node/16`).

How do I forcibly override the `destination` query string content for this submit handler?

This question is similar to this [D7 question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/form-redirect-not-working-if-destination-is-in-url) but since Drupal 8 has the Symfony routing system the answers there did not help me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To force a redirect remove the destination query string from the request:

```
\Drupal::request()->query->remove('destination');
```

After this you can also reset the RedirectDestination service, although this seems not to be necessary for a form:

```
\Drupal::destination()->set(NULL);
```

When you have already a URL object set it directly in $form_state:

```
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

---

With the release of Drupal 10.2.0 you can use

```
$form_state->setIgnoreDestination();
```

See https://www.drupal.org/node/3375113

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the [RedirectResponse Class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21RedirectResponse.php/class/RedirectResponse/8.2.x) ? I have this kind of callbacks, and it removes URL parameters.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

function MYMODULE_authfrontpageredirect_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  $response = new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => '16']));
  $response->send();
}
```

Comment: Sending a response is discouraged, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215372/redirectresponse-not-able-to-redirect-in-hook-entity-view-drupal-8/215385#comment263197_215372

Comment: Did not know that, thank you ! Do you know why it is discouraged ?

Comment: Because the job of the Drupal kernel is to return a response, not to send one. Sending a response doesn't stop the code. This can have unexpected results, because Drupal continues building the response and doesn't know that you've already sent one.