# Drupal 8 Form Redirect On Failed Validation

Tags: 8, forms, redirection

I have a form which, upon failed validation, should query a custom/non-Drupal table, and if that query is successful, to redirect the user to a custom page that is only accessible through a logged-in state (so I need to "fake" successful authentication even if the user does not exist in the official Drupal users table).

The query to the custom table essentially checks a secondary user list in non-Drupal format upon failing to authenticate the official way, and if successful, would redirect the user to another page where they could select a Drupal username and password combination in order to register them in the system / make an official account.

This is the relevant code inside my form validation method:

```
if ($this->userAuth->authenticate($form_state->getValue('name'), $password) == FALSE) {
    // other stuff
    $uid = $this->userAuth->authenticate($form_state->getValue('name'), $password);
    $form_state->set('uid', $uid);

    $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse('/path/destination');
    $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

I have also tried this instead of the new TrustedRedirectResponse:

```
    $redirect_path = "/path/destination";
    $url = url::fromUserInput($redirect_path);
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question, but generally if you redirect to an internal path you use the route name `$form_state->setRedirect('my.redirect.route');`

Comment: If there is a destination set, you need to reset it first, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250465/how-to-force-a-redirect-override-the-destination-query-string-in-the-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the redirect to happen immediately, you can do it like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;


$response = new RedirectResponse('/path/destination');

$response->send();
```

Comment: Sending and returning seems a bit like overkill. In a form validation or submit method you can't do either of it, put the response in $form_state instead and the form submitter will take care of returning the response at the right time.

Comment: Yeah, the return was unnecessary. I have edited and removed it. As for putting the response in the form state - it wouldn't kick in until form submission, while the poster indicated they wanted it immediately.

Comment: A [StackPHP](https://stackphp.com/) app like Drupal receives a request and returns a response. Sending the response breaks the interface REQ -> HttpKernel -> REP.

Comment: So how would you go about doing the redirect on a failed validation?

Comment: Validation and submitting are executed back to back, you should be able to put the redirect response in both. Only difference is, if you set a validation error in $form_state (which is not the case here), then submitting is stopped and the error is displayed in the form itself (which wouldn't make sense in case of a redirect).

Comment: Exactly. So how would you do a redirect in a failed validation? Doing a redirect upon a successful validation is straightforward, but I’m not aware of a way to make it happen upon a failed validation other than what I’ve done here.

Comment: The OP didn't set any validation error in $form_state. If he had, then this would indeed be a problem. Drupal can't send a form rebuild and a redirect at the same time.

Comment: The user wasn't looking to set a form rebuild, just a redirect - which is what I gave in my answer. Do you have a way to set a redirect using the stackPHP interface from a validation handler?

Comment: I was responding to your question about a failed validation. This leads to a form rebuild displaying the error. And then you can't send a redirect at the same time. - I think if you really need to get out of the form handling immediately the best option is to raise an exception and catch it in an event subscriber. Although this shouldn't be necessary because you have enough options in forms to react on user input. But as I've mentioned in the first comment, the OP didn't ask any question, so I vote to close.

Comment: The reason I asked the question is because your comment said that the method I used went against the stackPHP interface, but you didn't give an example of how it could be done properly. I'd like to know how to do it properly, and your explanation of using an exception and catching it in an event subscriber sounds interesting, so I'd like to see an example so that I can use it in the future. Can you please add one as a solution to this issue so that those of us who are doing it incorrectly using the method I have shown above can know how to do it correctly?

Comment: You can use EnforcedResponseException to terminate form processing and redirect: ```$response = new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('user.login', [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString()); throw new \Drupal\Core\Form\EnforcedResponseException($response); ```