# Redirect after updating nodes

Tags: 8, redirection

I've to redirect users, after updating a node, to `/node/NID` path and not to `/node/NID/latest` (I'm using content moderation).

I've tried to add this on hook_node_update() but have been ignored (without warning or errors):

```
if (!$entity->isNew()) {
    $path = URL::fromUserInput('/node/' . $entity->id())->toString();
    return new RedirectResponse($path);
}
```

Comment: Better to add this in hook_form_alter as a new submit handler, and then redirect inside of that.

Comment: Yes, and then don't return or send the redirect response, set the redirect in $form_state. Node forms often have set a destination too, then you need to handle both, see  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250465/how-to-force-a-redirect-override-the-destination-query-string-in-the-url

Answer (score 1):

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;    
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

function MYMODULE_node_update(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  $path = Url::fromUserInput('/node/'.$node->id())->toString();
  $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
  $response->send();
}
```

You have to use like above. You are just returning the redirect response. You need to send redirectresponse to given path.

Comment: Sending a response is not a good idea, see the duplicate question.

Comment: Suggest of Ajay works but I'll take a look to the duplicate questio, thanks!