# How to disable redirection to the node after node form submission

Tags: 8, nodes, redirection

I have a node form exposed in the front-end to allow visitors to add their organisation to the list of partners. Below the form, I have exposed view block with the list of existing partners.

When a visitor enters a new organisation to the list I want the form just to add a new node type "partner" and reload the page/block without redirecting to the node content (node/[node ID]).

At the beginning I ed taxonomy terms instead and it worked as it should, now I want to achieve the same with node entity.

I have tried various solutions but none of it works correctly and I didn't find much by googling it.

For example, this is not functioning:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_partners_form') {
    $form_state->disableRedirect(); // This is not functioning
  }
}
```

This does not work either:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_partners_form') {
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
        $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'THEME_node_form_submit';
      }
    }
  }
}

function THEME_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect(Url::fromUri('internal:/node/1')->toString());
}

=> Error: Route /partners does not exist.
```

Value of attribute action in the exposed node form is correct and therefore I think the proper solution should be elsewhere then altering form properties - probably it has more with the Drupal behaviour after adding a new node.

```
<form action="/en/partners">...</form>
```

Comment: Does the URL have a destination parameter? Then remove it and reset the RedirectDestination service, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250465/how-to-force-a-redirect-override-the-destination-query-string-in-the-url

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comment 4k4. Unfortunately, I didn't have enough time to find a proper solution so I just changed the redirection URL to the same content where the form is exposed.

```
function THEME_node_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state)  {
    $node_id = 1;
    $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
}
```

I'll try to find a more appropriate solution if I'll have some extra time before deadline :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you form code in particular, but another thought in finding a solution might be to modify the form action on-the-fly like this to get what you want:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    global $base_url;
    $form['#action'] = $base_url . '/whatever_you_like';
```

This might be a little extraordinary, but it might help in some special use cases depinding on your code and I must admit I did not test it with:

```
function THEME_node_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
```

Good luck :-)