# How to determine the route for the add node page of a custom entity type?

Tags: routes

I have a node type **question** that I want users to be able to create rapidly.  So, after adding a question, I want them to be redirected to `/node/add/question` to immediately do it again.

This is my code so far:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'node_question_form':
      foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
          $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_node_form_submit';
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}

function MYMODULE_node_form_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  // https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/250474/5147
  \Drupal::request()->query->remove('destination');
  $form_state->setRedirect('node.add_page');
}
```

This redirects to `/node/add`, but I want to redirect to `/node/add/question`.  I tried digging through the route options in PHPStorm but I couldn't find anything that gets to the create page for a custom content type.

Comment: A good way to learn about specific routes is to look at the module's *.routing.yml* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `node.add` route, which has a `node_type` parameter.

```
$form_state->setRedirect('node.add', ['node_type' => 'question']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to redirect to the "add page" of type question,replace

```
$form_state->setRedirect('node.add_page');
```

by

```
$form_state->setRedirect('node.add', ['node_type' => 'question']);
```