Redirect Not Working
I can't figure out why my redirect of the login form submit hook is not working:
redirect route:
mfa.otp_form:
  path: "/mfa-otp-form/{uid}"
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mfa\Form\OnetimePasscodeForm'
    _title: "Onetime Passcode"
  requirements:
    _role: "authenticated"

hook_user_login_form_alter
function mfa_form_user_login_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mfa_user_login_form_submit';

  $form['fp'] = ['#type' => 'hidden',];
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mfa/fp';
}

hook_user_loging_form_submit:
function mfa_user_login_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void
{
  $fp = $form_state->getValue('fp');
  $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

  if (Functions::hasFingerprint($uid, $fp))
    return;

  $user = User::load($uid);
  $passcode = Functions::passcode($user);

  $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
  $session->set('mfa_otp', $passcode);
  $session->set('mfa_otp_time', time());
  $session->save();

  Functions::mailPasscode($user, $passcode);

  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('You are using an unrecognized device. For your security 
    enter the onetime passcode emailed to you at ' . $user->getEmail());

  $form_state->setRedirect('mfa.otp_form', ['uid' => $uid]);
}

OnetimePasscodeForm.php
<?php // $Id$

namespace Drupal\mfa\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\mfa\Functions;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

class OnetimePasscodeForm extends FormBase
{
  public function getFormId(): string
  {
    return 'mfa_otp_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, int $uid = 0): array
  {
    global $base_url;

    $form['passcode'] = [
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#title' => $this->t('Passcode'),
      '#required' => true,
      '#maxlength' => 8,
      '#description' => "One time passcode(OTP)",
    ];

    $form['uid'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#default_value' => $uid,
    ];

    $form['fp'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ]; 

    $form["resend"] = [
      '#markup' => "<p><a href=\"{$base_url}/mfa-resend-otp/{$uid}\">Resend onetime passcode(OTP)</a></p>",
    ];

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mfa/fp';

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void
  {
    $passcode = $form_state->getValue('passcode');

    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $otp = (int) ($session->get('mfa_otp') ?: 0);
    $otp_time = (int) ($session->get('mfa_otp_time') ?: 0);

    if ($otp == 0 || $otp_time == 0) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('passcode', 'Onetime passcode is missing in your session.');
      $uid = $form_state->getValue('uid');
      $user = User::load($uid);
      \Drupal::logger('mfa')->error('Onetime passcode is missing in ' . $user->getDisplayName()
        . "($uid)'s" . ' session.');
      return;
    }

    if ($passcode != $otp)
      $form_state->setErrorByName('passcode', "Passcode is not valid.");

    if (time() - $otp_time > \Drupal::config('mfa.settings')->get('passcode_lifetime'))
      $form_state->setErrorByName('passcode', "Passcode has expired. Please click the resend link below 
        and generate a new passcode and try again.");
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void
  {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->remove('mfa_otp');
    $session->remove('mfa_otp_time');
    $session->save();

    $uid = $form_state->getValue('uid');

    Functions::addFingerprint($uid, $form_state->getValue('fp'));

    \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Onetime passcode authenticated successfully.'));

    $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
  }
}

I can display the otp form by typing https://xxxx/mfa-otp-form/1 in the browser command field. I get no errors in the log. I've logged debug statements and the mfa module is executed after the main bncreports module. The redirect route is set in the form_state. I've weighted mfa = 10, bncreports = 0.

Don't have time to put an answer in properly so apologies for the tidbit - take a look at line 158 of the core UserLoginForm; there are two different methods which can affect the redirect, you need to reproduce that example in your own code and affect the destination URL parameter

I looked at that. I'm doing the same thing but with a different route. I don't understand why the redirect route does not appear to be getting replaced. I do it in my main module by setting the route name to ''. That works but my mfa module does not appear to be overwriting it to 'mfa.otp_form' . There is also the possibility of a destination param in the query part of the Url.

A few remarks. The destination param is resolved before the response is sent to the client and overwrites any redirect in custom code. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250465/how-to-force-a-redirect-override-the-destination-query-string-in-the-url. Never close the session $session->save(); in custom code, Drupal does this automatically. Why does the question contain so much code of the target when in fact it's only about how to hook into the core user login form and set a redirect? The issue could be demonstrated with a few lines of code.

I guess I did not need to post the OnetimePasscodeForm.php code. Didn't know save() closed the session. I thought it just saved the changes to the sessions table.

I guess you got to remove any possible destination query data from the redirect url or maybe replace it with a new destination if that is what you want.
Adding:
$form_state->setIgnoreDestination();

to "function mfa_user_login_form_submit" solved the problem.
